# 24 hour Countdown timer in local timezone using moment.js in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic5

I am trying to implement a 24 hour countdown-timer in [hh:mm:ss] format using moment.js which will start at [23:59:59] stop at [00:00:00].
what I am trying to achieve here is that the timer should be displayed in my local time zone and not UTC and it should not stop when i navigate between pages or even when i close the app. also i heard that we cannot use any background mode plugins as apps store will reject apps using such plugins.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have already attempted?

Comment: My TS Code time: any;

displayTime() {
  this.time = moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(this.counter++).format('HH : mm : ss');
}

startTime() {
  if(this.runClock == null) {
    this.runClock = setInterval(() => {
      this.displayTime();
    },1000)
  }
}
In my HTML I call {{ time }}.